# Return a value from an async block in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to return a value from a function where the return value is inside the then() block.
Cypress throws a bunch of errors that I am mixing async and sync code. I tried returning a Promise and resolving it, but that threw up errors too.

```
cy.get('.btn.btn-primary')
  .each(function ($el, index, $list) {
    // Lot of code
 
    if (price < minPrice) minPrice = price
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.log(minPrice); //This works fine
    return minPrice; //This throws ERROR
  })
```

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alias to save the value and then later use it something like this.

```js
cy.get('.btn.btn-primary')
  .each(function ($el, index, $list) {
    // Lot of code

    if (price < minPrice) minPrice = price
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.log(minPrice) //This works fine
    cy.wrap(minPrice).as('minPrice') //Saved as alias
  })

//In your test you can use it as
cy.get('@minPrice').then((minPrice) => {
  //Access minPrice here
  cy.log(minPrice) //prints minPrice
})
```